# ChangeNotifierProvider for multiple inheritence

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

I have the following service structure instead of having a single huge class A:

```
class A extends ChangeNotifier {
...
}

class B extends A {
...
}

class C extends A {
...
}
class D extends A {
...
}
```

I can do the following:

```
 MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => A()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => B()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => C()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => D()),
      ],
```

But is there any other way to provide all the child classes in one step rather than providing each one separately in a `MultiProvider`.

Comment: I think you would have to create a new class to hold all of the instances, and then just provide that.  There is not built in dart process for "initialize all child classes" of a certain object, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I tried it already, but it didn't work.